# Writing a floating point multiplication function in C

Tags: c, floating-point

In my Computer Science course I have been assigned to write a function which takes in two floating point arguments and returns the result of their multiplication in the C language

```
float multiply(float foo, float bar);
```

I am not allowed to use any libraries or any floating point operations other than the assignment operator =

I understand how floating points are represented in C and I have extracted the exponents and fractions by doing this:

```
union sp_item { float frep; unsigned irep; };
union sp_item num;
num.frep = foo;
int exponent = ((num.irep >> 23) - 0x7f);
int frac = (num.irep << 9);
```

I understand that I need to add the exponents (simple enough), and multiply the two fractions. The thing is I have no idea where to get started to multiply the fractions. I was thinking of converting the fraction into its hexadecimal representation as a string (ex: 0.5 would be "80000000"), and writing an algorithm to multiply the bits that way, but since I can't use any of the C libraries I have no idea how I would go about doing that. Could someone point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** It occured to me that floats might not be represented the same way on all systems. In this course we assume the first bit is the sign, the next 8 bits are the exponent, and the last 23 bits are the fraction.

**Edit:** This is what I have gotten so far. When I try and multiply the two integers, I just get zero unless I enter `(long long)((long long)xRep * (long long)yRep)` into my debuggers watch list

```
#include <stdio.h>
union sp_item
{
  float frep;
  unsigned irep;
};

int main() {
float x = 0.25;
float y = 0.5;
union sp_item xUnion;
union sp_item yUnion;
xUnion.frep = x; yUnion.frep = y;

unsigned xExp = (xUnion.irep >> 23) - 0x7f;
unsigned yExp = (yUnion.irep >> 23) - 0x7f;

unsigned xRep = (xUnion.irep << 9);
unsigned yRep = (yUnion.irep << 9);


xRep = (xRep >> 1) | 0x80000000;
yRep = (yRep >> 1) | 0x80000000;

long long final = (long long)((long long)xRep * (long long)yRep);

printf("iRep: %x * 2^%d\n", xRep, xExp);
printf("iRep: %x * 2^%d\n", yRep, yExp);
printf("%01611x\n", final);
}
```

Comment: You have `ldexp/frexp` to set/retrieve mantissa and exponent portably (but most often slowly).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just multiply the fractions (extracted to their int representation) using the integer multiplication operator, `*`?

Comment: He said he can only use the assignment operator.

Comment: No, he said he couldn't use any **floating point** operations other than the assignment operator. I am suggesting using integer operations to multiply integers.

Comment: How would I go about extracting it to its integer representation?

I know the integer representation is just the hex representation reversed, but I don't know how to reverse it without converting a string, and I'm not sure how to convert it to a string without using a library.

Comment: You already have the integer representation of the fraction in the `frac` field of your structure. You need to shift in the implied leading `1` into each fraction; multiply the integers using the integer multiply operator; renormalize and remove the leading one from the result and adjust the result's exponent based on the renormalization.  The "integer representation is just the hex representation reversed" is not even remotely true.

Comment: When debugging in Netbeans if I put `(long long)((long long)xRep * (long long)yRep)` in the debuggers watch list I get a number, but when I try to say `long long denorm = (long long)((long long)xRep * (long long)yRep)` it always sets denorm to zero. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

24 + 24 < 64, so you can use `long long` multiplication. Long longs are guaranteed to be big enough to hold numbers from -(2^63-1) to (2^63-1)

Or you can split the number in two part (low order 16 bits + high order 8 bits) and use 32-bit multiplication (note that `unsigned long` is guaranteed to provide at least 32 bits).

Take care of normalizing the result correctly afterwards.

Comment: For the purpose of the above word-length calculation, it's 24-bit input (there's the implied leading 1 in each mantissa).

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point might be useful reading. The mantissa can only have a certain range and you will need to adjust the exponent to take this into account

Comment: BTW - For us oldies I wrote floating point arithmetic on a 6502 processor - what fun.